# How to embed a clock oscillator inside a digital block? Specifically, how is this defined for Synopsys DC?

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, synthesis

I have to embed a clock oscillator inside my logic block for layout purposes. It's not an option to leave this block out and just bring the clock port in. Is there any way to define an internal net as a clock for other sub modules? All I want is to use the output port of the osicllator (which itself is am embedded submodule) as my clock for the rest of the design. 
Anyone have ideas as to how this is done?

Comment: Verilog or VHDL? (Please add the tag)

Comment: How is your oscillator defined in Design Compiler? (e.g. a Liberty block, HDL black box, actual HDL..)

Comment: My deisgn is all VHDL. The oscillator is just a hdl black box with just the output caps defined in a separate '.lib' file.I'm trying to define the output port of this black box as the clock for the rest of the design.
In my constraints file, I'm trying to define it as follows:

create_clock OSCILLATOR_INSTANCE/CLKPORT -name CLOCK_INT -period xyz -waveform [yada yada]

Design Compiler seems to have a problem with this. Is this even remotely correct?

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in my designs is

`create_clock -name CLOCK_INT -period 47 [get_pins OSCILLATOR_INSTANCE/CLKPORT]`

If memory serves me correctly (and check the DC guide to be sure) the target of the `create_clock` command needs to be a "pin object" and not just the pin name. The command `get_pins` returns a pin object, and if you specify the exact pin as the argument, it doesn't require any additional filtering.

Comment: Turns out I am super dumb. I was just using the instance name with a wrong case all along. Thanks!